# Excel formula: How to concatenate multiple match results addresses (instead of values)

Tags: excel, excel-formula, excel-match

First of all thanks for reading my post and for trying to help me.

I would like to know if it is possible to match multiple values from a column and concatenate (separated by a comma for instance) their addresses instead of their values.

[image]

The picture shows an example of what I want to do.
As looking for Dogs, I get the address of each occurrence instead of its value.

I have used both AGGREGATE and TEXTJOIN as well as INDEX and MATCH formulas but I do not know how to use these in order to get the addresses of the matches.

Any help is much appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: Can I ask why you need/want to do this, out of curiosity?

Comment: I have a Workbook with a few Worksheets.

One of the worksheets (1) has a column where I have values that are usually unique but may be repeated depending on the scenario.

In a different worksheet (2), I have the same values without repeating them.

In worksheet (2) I want to ensure that:
A) That value is present in the worksheet (1)
B) The address of that value so that the user can check the entire row for that value in the worksheet (1)
C) If the value is repeated, provide the addresses of the other occurrences.

Answer (score 0):

You need to also use the `ADDRESS` function:

*Note that the formula below will adjust for whatever column contains your `animals` list, in case it happens not be column `A`.*

```
   =TEXTJOIN(",",TRUE,ADDRESS(AGGREGATE(15,6,1/(theAnimal=animals)*ROW(animals),ROW(INDIRECT("1:"&COUNTIF(animals,theAnimal)))),COLUMNS(animals),4))
```

Depending on your version of Excel, you may need to enter this as an **array formula**. To enter/confirm an **array formula**, hold down <kbd>ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>shift</kbd> while hitting <kbd>enter</kbd>. If you do this correctly, Excel will place braces `{...}` around the formula seen in the formula bar.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Or using this array formula (Ctrl+Shift+Enter) without ADDRESS function :

```
=TEXTJOIN( ",",1,"A"&AGGREGATE(15,6,ROW(A1:A12)/(A1:A12="Dog"),ROW(INDIRECT("1:"&COUNTIF(A:A,"Dog")))))
```

[image]